# WIA Defining CLSID_WiaDevMgr2 & IID_IWiaDevMgr2

Tags: c++, wia

I am starting to work with WIA 2.0 and, as so many others, have started from the MS provided tutorial & example code (see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629848%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Unlike the others what I have been unable to find is where the GUIDs CLSID_WiaDevMgr2 & IID_IWiaDevMgr2 are defined.

My code compiles - the variables are declared in wia_lh.h - but fails to build with error messages that these two symbols are unresolved i.e. not defined.

```
HRESULT CWiaSP::CreateWiaDeviceManager()
{
    pWiaDevMgr = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_WiaDevMgr2, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IWiaDevMgr2, (void**)&pWiaDevMgr ); 

    return hr;

}
```

How to identify the GUID value for these: can this be done programmatically, or are they well known values that are defined somewhere?

Comment: Looking in the registry I have found both WIA.DeviceManager and WIA.DevMgr that specify a CLSID but not sure which (if either) is applicable to CLSID_WiaDevMgr2. My understanding is that such CLSIDs are universal and constant so I am puzzled why the two I have highlighted in original question are not pre-defined on my system.

Comment: Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, add wiaguid.lib

Comment: Thx Hans - I note now that this .lib was listed as required for WIA1's IWiaDevMgr but not for IWiaDevMgr2 by MS